# How to notify Google about changes to my website so that it updates the search results right away?

Tags: seo, google

I have tried notifying Google via "Fetch as Google" & via "Google Ping", but I have seen no effect on Google search engine result.

I have done some changes to my website. All the updates are very important so I want to notify Google.  How do I do it?

Comment: Simple; Just wait.

Comment: I couldn't find an exact duplicate question, but we have others that address similar topics.   See also: [Need Google to recrawl the pages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52757/need-google-to-recrawl-the-pages), [How can I get Google to remove links to my site from their index and then recrawl my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/how-can-i-get-google-to-remove-links-to-my-site-from-their-index-and-then-recraw)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do it login to your Google Webmaster Tools account, navigate to **Crawl menu** sections and click on **Fetch as Google** and **click Fetch**.

The change will not be immediate and it really depends on when Google decided to crawl your site again.

Comment: It seems that the Fetch as Google behavior has changed in the past year or there about. It will fetch the page, but not necessarily update the index as a result. Instead, it will submit a second fetch via the regular robot within a day or two and update the index that way. The reason (I believe) is that the Fetch as Google option has been abused. It is a fair compromise if you ask me.

Comment: This answer is half-correct, in that this process now (at time of comment) allows you to then "**Submit to Index**". More details on this from Google here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide a mechanism for webmasters to get changes into the Google index immediately.   Any changes you make will take at least a day or two, and in some cases as much as a couple weeks to get indexed.

Google does this because it makes it harder for black hats to test out techniques for ranking better.   When changes take a while to be reflected in the index, the hackers don't have as much time to try out as many things.

"Fetch as Google" and "Google Ping" are the best you are going to be able to do.   Those alert Google that there are changes.   Google may take a while to act on that information and update the index.

Comment: Not quite correct. The submit to index function allows for _immediate_ indexation of content (I've tested this an confirmed a brand new URL was indexed within 30 minutes). There are some caveats, but i've managed to get a significant amount of content introduced very quickly using this method.