# Google takes 7 days to crawl and index new content despite submitting a site map in search console

Tags: search-engine-indexing, xml-sitemap

I have WordPress site and i have submitted XML site map.  It takes Google takes more than 7 days to crawl and index new content. There are no errors in Google Search Console with crawling or indexing.

I am seeing this problem with my other sites as well since 2017.

Why is Google slow in indexing? Is Google finding it difficult to update index as the Web is growing larger and larger?

I did submit the site map through robots.txt as well.

Comment: Usually Google learns by itself how often your website is updated. How often do you update your website with new content?

Comment: 2 posts everyday

Comment: I haven't noticed a similar delay, is the domain name very new as well? If your sitemap is setup correctly then his is a Q only Google can answer.

Comment: The site i started 4 months ago with 120 pages. About 100 pages already indexed.

Comment: Hi pbu what are you asking? " 4 months ago with 120 pages. About 100 pages" - are you're asking about the other 20 pages? Google may consider them to be similar to other existing indexed pages on the same site.

These are different situations. Initial indexing of a brand new site is probably dependent on Google's backlog of sites to index and only they know what their priority criteria would be.

Comment: See also: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: See also: [How to notify Google about changes to my website so that it updates the search results right away?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88127/how-to-notify-google-about-changes-to-my-website-so-that-it-updates-the-search-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your website is New and Google has yet given it much consideration. Google updates some websites data after a few minutes or but can takes days or even weeks to update some websites.

It all depend on how Google prioritize your website. However, you can submit new Urls to google manually here https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url